# Circular reference when using VichUploader with KnpGaufrette and Doctrine in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, gaufrette, vichuploaderbundle

I tried to use the following setup in my Symfony2 project:

- [VichUploader Bundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) for handling file uploads
- [KnpGaufrette Bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle) which should be used by VichUploader as a storage adapter

**Problem:** As soon as i try to use the Gaufrette storage adapter "doctrine_dbal" I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.dbal.default_connection", path: "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager -> doctrine.dbal.default_connection -> vich_uploader.upload_handler -> vich_uploader.storage.gaufrette -> knp_gaufrette.filesystem_map -> gaufrette.storage_fs_filesystem".
```

The problem occurs as soon as Symfony tries to check the configuration, e.g. on

```
app/console cache:clear
```

How can I resolve this issue?

## My Setup

My project setup is the default setup of `symfony/framework-standard-edition` with version `2.5.*` without AcmeDemo Bundle.

I simply did add the Bundles via Composer:

```
composer require knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle vich/uploader-bundle
```

... added them to AppKernel's `registerBundles()`:

```
//...
$bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        new Vich\UploaderBundle\VichUploaderBundle(), //NEW 
        new Knp\Bundle\GaufretteBundle\KnpGaufretteBundle(), //NEW
    );
//...
```

... and added the following configuration to `config.yml`, which is based on the docs [VichUploader with Gaufrette](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/v0.14.0/Resources/doc/storage/gaufrette.md#configuration) and [KnpGaufrette with Doctrine DBAL](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle/blob/v0.1.7/README.markdown#doctrine-dbal-doctrine_dbal):

```
# ...
knp_gaufrette:
    stream_wrapper: ~

    adapters:
        storage_adapter:
            doctrine_dbal:
                connection_name: default
                table: data_storage
                columns:
                    key: id
                    content: file
                    mtime: mtime
                    checksum: checksum

    filesystems:
        storage_fs:
            adapter:    storage_adapter



vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    storage:   gaufrette

    mappings:
        storage:
            uri_prefix:         /images/products
            upload_destination: storage_fs
```

Comment: Why does the doctrine.dbal.default_connection service have dependency on vich_uploader.upload_handler? I'd start with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Version 0.14.0 (https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/issues/370) which got fixed in this commit:
https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/commit/4abf4180afaf318a66d3e34736c5a14aa0883bd3